# Unobtrusive Validation when using Jquery On Vs Live

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, validation

I'm noticing a difference in behavior in form submission and validation when using jquery's "On" vs jquery's "Live".  It seems like when using On, form validation is fired but even if the form is invalid, the method still continues and submits the form.  This is in contrast to live, where if the form is invalid, it appears that the callback function is not even called.

For example

```
    form.live('submit', function(evt) {
        console.log('before prevent default'); //WONT EVEN GET HERE
        evt.preventDefault();
        console.log("After prevent default!");
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(_ajaxSubmitSettings());
    });
```

VS

```
    form.on('submit', function(evt) {
        console.log('before prevent default');
        evt.preventDefault();
        console.log("After prevent default!");
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(_ajaxSubmitSettings()); //Calls Ajax Submit, generating an error if form is invalid
    });
```

I know how to work around this and it's not holding me up, I'm just wondering why there is this difference in behavior.

And for the record, I know I shouldn't be using Live anymore.

Comment: Which version of jquery? (`.live()` was depreciated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9)

Comment: jquery 1.7.2.  Based on this behavior, I feel like live is calling validate() and valid() on the form before the callback is fired.  Whereas on is just calling validate() and doesn't check to see if the form is valid prior to calling the callback.